# Function returning another function

Tags: c++, declaration, language-lawyer

The question may be sounded quite silly, but why can't we do so? I mean, a declarator like the following:

```
void (foo())();
```

I've read the section 8.3.5 of the current C++ standard and didn't find how it implies from what said there.

Here is what the standard said about that:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form

```
D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seqopt
ref-qualifieropt exception-specificationopt attribute-specifier-seqopt
```

> and the type of the contained declarator-id in the declaration T D1 is
>   “derived-declarator-type-list T”, the type of the declarator-id in D
>   is “derived-declarator-type-list function of
>   (parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifierseqopt ref-qualifieropt
>   returning T”.

So, formally, from that definition implies that my declration is a valid function declration. `T D1`, in my case has the form `void foo()` which is a perfectly valid declration. What did I miss?

Comment: You can in fact return a function pointer. Which is what a function identifier  decays to when passed or returned from other functions.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know, but my question is not about how to return a function pointer. It's in fact a lngauage-lawyer question. I'm sorry for forgetting to add the tag.

Comment: You can return `std::function` objects, like so:  http://ideone.com/Glc7xs

Comment: @St.Antario  Could you please put the cite you don't understand from section 8.3.5 into your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ just a second.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Couldn't you glance at the updated question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've read the section 8.3.5 of the current C++ standard

Obviously not very carefully. §8.3.5 [dcl.fct]/p8:

> Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function,
>   although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to
>   such things.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you can't create a temporary object of a function. However if you're planning to do something like this try returning a pointer to a function. Try this:

```
int (*fun())();
```

Pointer values can be returned by a function. You can't return a function because there is no function type.

Comment: There absolutely _is_ a function type. In fact there are near-infinite function types...

Comment: I think where it gets tricky is whether "function objects" or  "function values" exist. Functions have a return _type_, and a function call (unless it throws) throw must return a value of that type. Assume that a function could have a return type that is a function type, what would its return statement look like?